# Create a cross shape in CSS

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

IS it possible, I know all the following shapes are possible in this link:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

but cross must be possible too. When I say cross I mean like this:

[image]

Comment: Use two elements layered over each other? OR even better: one element with an ::after pseudo element (or ::before)

Comment: You can't do it with a single element .. Better go for SVG or canvas...

Comment: The cross has actually been added to css-tricks now:  https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could achieve something like this with pseudoelements only:

http://jsbin.com/upiyoc/1/edit

```
#cross {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}

#cross:before, #cross:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #d00;
}

#cross:before {
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: -15%;
  height: 100%;
}

#cross:after {
  top: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The size of the cross will proportionally scale, according to the `width` and `height` of the `#cross` element

---

Update: another solution (using less code) could simply involve multiple linear-gradients (without pseudolements) e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxwgPo

```
#cross {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 35%, 
                                         #d00 35%, 
                                         #d00 65%,  
                                         transparent 65%),

              linear-gradient(to right, transparent 35%, 
                                         #d00 35%, 
                                         #d00 65%,  
                                         transparent 65%),
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why "absolute" is required? I tested it on codepen and if you change it relative or take that out, it won't show...even with the specified height and width pixels....help..its driving me crazy not knowing ;(

Comment: without position: absolute you should give them a display (or float) otherwise the pseudolements cannot be visible (they are not real elements, and their `content` property is empty) so here position: absolute makes unnecessary to use float (or display) property

Comment: oh ok...so any type of pseudo element with no content HAS to have absolute? can you show me where it says that in the w3. Things like this I wish i knew how to look up in that thing. lol

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is. You just have to use two elements : See http://jsfiddle.net/92XTx/2/

The enclosing div is `relative`ly positioned so that both children can be absolutely positioned.

```
#cross {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Here they are both absolutely positioned:

```
#cross div {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
```

to make them superpose.

And then create your shapes:

```
.cross-vertical {
    left: 33%;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cross-horizontal {
    top: 33%;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because all the answers I see here look either lengthy or vendor-prefix-dependent,

```css
#cross { 
  background: red; 
  height: 100px; 
  position: relative; 
  left: 50px;
  width: 20px; 
} 
#cross:after { 
  background: red; 
  content: ""; 
  height: 20px; 
  left: -40px; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 40px; 
  width: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="cross"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a regular '+' plus character together with a `text-stroke`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fuey193n/)** ([Webkit,Android only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke))

```css
div {
  font-size: 80px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Transform can be easily used to achieve plus shape

```
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.cross:before, .cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 21px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.cross:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.cross:after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```