# How to create a cross with pure css

Tags: html, css

How to create a cross (x) inside a div that cointains an image? The cross must also overlap the image, is possible do it in pure css or I must to create a new image with the cross?

Comment: Yea, this is possible - pretty easy actually. It can be accomplished several different ways.

Comment: I specified it in the question, cross (x).

Comment: May I have missed something, or some UTF-8 characters could simply do the job? like ✕ (U+2715), ✗ (U+2717) or ✘ (U+2718)

Comment: If you're trying to watermark your images, be aware that this approach would have no security.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

If I were you I'd opt for the easy solution, just put an X within a div and give that div your background image

http://jsfiddle.net/vGqDJ/

```
.image {
background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg');
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but I'd probably go with &times; - more delete-like in most fonts

Comment: And if image is not a background image but an html element?

Comment: That's just it, you'd have to change your img to an element with a background image http://jsfiddle.net/vGqDJ/2/

Answer (score 10):

**CSS-**

```
#cross {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#cross:before, #cross:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #d00;
}

#cross:before {
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: -15%;
  height: 100%;
}

#cross:after {
  top: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/r6E9p/)

Ways to reproduce this-

Step-

Create a simple square by adding no background color to it-

```
 #cross {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       position: relative;
    }
```

Second step-

```
`CSS gives you compatibility to play with sudo-elements`.
```

There is always content space onto every element in css.

Example- 
[Adding before after sudo-element](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/fSHHx/)

Third step-
By aligning these before after elements `position:absolute` to relative parent you get the shape.

Last step-
Transform rotate it the way you want.
an example-

[Transform in css](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/fSHHx/2/)

By the way @Adam's way of doing this is clever and once preferred by me.

Comment: Thanks for replace, what about compatibility?

Comment: @user2843341, Don't worry about it.

Comment: Nice job copying the answer right off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359787/create-a-cross-shape-in-css

Comment: Hey Manoz really liked the way you achieved this please can you explain this would like to learn how each css property make a work.. Thank you!

Comment: This is way overcomplicated. Why not just use a UTF-8 character? http://jsfiddle.net/mpaQS/

Comment: @Adam, With full css you have more controle of the view. However in this case, UTF-8 is as usefull as css :p

Comment: @nkmol - I am using full CSS. More importantly, I'm not using pseudo elements (won't work in IE7) and I'm not using transforms (won't work in IE8).

Answer (score 7):

You people are way over thinking the answers. Use a simple `&times;` symbol - 100% cross browser, no transforms/pseudo elements needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/mpaQS/

**EDIT**

I realize you may also not understand the concepts of relative/absolute positioning.

Your container needs to be positioned relatively, and your "X" needs to be positioned absolutely. Like the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wVdvu/