# How can I create a cross in CSS?

Tags: css, less

How can I create a cross in CSS?  I just need a cross that will be 1 pixel width and 20 pixels in height. I have tried the code from this question "[Create a cross shape in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359787/create-a-cross-shape-in-css)". But it gets all crazy on me and turns to be only 1 line.

Comment: Use a Unicode character. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark.

Comment: People need to quit doing this. CSS styles HTML elements. It is not a drawing program.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it for you:

```
<div class="cross"></div>

<style>
    .cross {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        position: relative;
        //-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
        //-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
        //transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
    }
    .cross:after, .cross:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        background: red;
    }
    .cross:after {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 1px;
    }
    .cross:before {
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 1px; 
    }
<style>
```

Comment: Please elaborate, for the sake of future users, how exactly this resolves the askers problem. Welcome to stack overflow recommended reading [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use a little coffeescrpit and css with this to make it even better.

**HTML**

```
<span class="cross"></span>
```

**CSS3**

```
@import "compass/css3";

body {background: #111;}

$cross-width: 15px;
$cross-thick: 1px;

.cross{
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.cross,
.cross:before,
.cross:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: $cross_thick;
    height: $cross_width;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.cross:before,
.cross:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: ($cross_width - $cross_thick)/ 2;
    left: -($cross_width - $cross_thick)/ 2;
    width: ($cross_width - $cross_thick)/ 2;
    height: $cross_thick;
}

.cross:after {
    left: $cross-thick;
}
```

Comment: How is CoffeeScript related to this?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from **Jim Bash**'s solution, I modified it to be more general and allow custom *thickness*.

**CSS**:

```
.cross {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    //-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
    //-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
    //transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
}
.cross:after, .cross:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: red;
}
.cross:after {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top:-5px;    //half of heigth
}
.cross:before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10px; 
    margin-left:-5px;    //half of width
}
```

The key is to set a width and height of two `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes and then *apply them a negative margin (on appropriate direction) equal to half of their thickness*.

If you use a pre-processor like LESS, this could be optimized:

**LESS**:

```
@cross-size:30px;
@cross-thickness:10px;
@cross-color:red;

.cross {
    height:@cross-size;
    width:@cross-size;
    position: relative;
    //-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
    //-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
    //transform: rotate(45deg); // this will make the cross an X
}
.cross:after, .cross:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background:@cross-color;
}
.cross:after {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:@cross-thickness;
    margin-top:-(@cross-thickness/2);    //half of heigth
}
.cross:before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:@cross-thickness; 
    margin-left:-(@cross-thickness/2);    //half of width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cross:after {
    content: "\271d"
}
```

```html
<span class="cross"></span>
```

Voila you have cross, if you want different then check UNICODE table